How to build a .deb in archlinux if bindeb-pkg is not available?
I'm running EndeavourOS Arch, and I'm trying to build the Linux Kernel to deploy within a debian / Ubuntu system. The files are usually in .deb format, however I noticed that the bindeb-pkg package isn't available in Arch.
I don't want to set up my development environment in the Ubuntu system as it gets re-imaged often, and would prefer not to use a virtual machine within my Arch as I usually SSH into it from whatever device I have at the moment.
I am not very familiar with containers like docker and so, but I guess I'll take a look at trying to run some kind of docker container... but would prefer to just use straight up system without any containers... (Yes I do understand it helps a lot to set up containers).
If anyone knows how to do something like
"make -j24 bindeb-pkg"
And have the .deb packages output in .tar.xz or similar. Or even output them as:
linux-firmware-image-VERSIONS.deb
linux-headers-VERSIONS.deb
linux-image-VERSIONS.deb
linux-libc-dev_VERSIONS.deb
If anyone know how to do this within Arch that'd be awesome.
Thank you

You need to install Debian packaging tools.
Since these are not available in the Arch Linux repositories by default, you can use yay to install them from the AUR.
yay -S dpkg debhelper devscripts

Now after configuring and building the kernel.
Run:
make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers

The .deb packages should be seen in the current kernel source root directory.
